# Javascript alert function in jss file

Tags: javascript, string, alert

I have a problem where I want to show a bunch of variables in an alert box when I click on a button on the webpage.

I don't want to create a bunch of variables in a XHTML file and then output those since I already calculated everything in my javascript file. I referenced the Javascript file to my XHTML file and the variables show up if i just do a plain document.write

The variables are just numbers I calculated on a range of values. I want to display them in an alert box when I click on a button on the webpage itself. Now I can display them in an alert box when I go to the webpage, but I can't figure out how to display them when I click on a button.

For example,:

My .jss file contains the following:

```
var num5 = 5;
var num6 = 6;
var num7 = 7;
var num8 = 8;
var num9 = 9;
var num10= 10;
```

My xhtml file:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtmll/DTD/xhtmll-strict.dtd">

 <html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>ShowNums.html</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "test.js">
        </script>
        <input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Click" />    
    </body>
</html>
```

I referenced my .jss file to my XHTML file and want to display those numbers. I can easily encode them into an alert but I would rather have a popup alert box that would display them when the user clicks on a button(i.e. the Click button). How would I do this? I tried looking for help but I can't seem to find it :\

Comment: Don't you mean `.js` and not `.jss`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just looking for this `show_alert()` function?

```
function show_alert() {
    var msg = num5 + ", " + num6 + ", " + num7 + ", " + num8 + ", " + num9 + ", " + num10;
    alert(msg);    // shows "5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"
}
```

Comment: ...and a way to bind it to the `value="Click"` button.

Comment: Ah that's exactly what I was looking for. I guess I was thinking about the show_alert function totally wrong! The book I was looking at didn't have an info on show_alert so I was totally lost. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @StephenP - I didn't see where the OP asked about the value, but it's available as `this.value` in the click handler.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I was just using that `value=` as a way to refer to the button, I hadn't grasped that he attached it with an *inline* handler (cough *urp*)